# sort the values in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am struggling to get sorting the values from multiple arrays groups.
I want group the values based upon same year and same  month respective of same array and multiple  arrays.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<message:GenericData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:generic="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/generic"
 xmlns:message="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/message"
 xmlns:common="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/common">

    <message:DataSet structureRef="BBK_SEDI" >
        <generic:Series> 
            <generic:SeriesKey>  
                <generic:Value id="BBK_SEDI_CALCULATION" value="ABZINS7"></generic:Value>        
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id="BBK_ID" value="BBSDI.M.ABZINS7.R01"></generic:Value>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value="2015-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                <generic:ObsValue value="3.07"></generic:ObsValue>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value="2016-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                <generic:ObsValue value="3.05"></generic:ObsValue> 
            </generic:Obs>
        </generic:Series>
        <generic:Series>
            <generic:SeriesKey>       
                <generic:Value id="BBK_SEDI_CALCULATION" value="ABZINS7"></generic:Value>                       
            </generic:SeriesKey>
            <generic:Attributes>
                <generic:Value id="BBK_ID" value="BBSDI.M.ABZINS7.R02"></generic:Value>
            </generic:Attributes>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value="2015-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                <generic:ObsValue value="1.07"></generic:ObsValue>
            </generic:Obs>
            <generic:Obs>
                <generic:ObsDimension value="2016-01"></generic:ObsDimension>
                <generic:ObsValue value="1.05"></generic:ObsValue>
            </generic:Obs> 
        </generic:Series>
    </message:DataSet>
</message:GenericData>
```

My XSLT provides gives the values from same arrays not from different  arrays

```
**XSLT**

    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:n0="http://sap.com/xi/SAPGlobal20/Global" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:generic="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/generic"
     xmlns:message="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/message"
     xmlns:common="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/common"
     xmlns:ns1="urn:siemens.com:Rates:SIE_I_T_S4_FIN1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi map generic java n0 message common ns1 ext exsl" xmlns:xslt-version="MonthlyDiscounts_XSLT_26/06/2022" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
        <xsl:template match="message:DataSet">
            <ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent>
            <xsl:for-each select="./generic:Series " >
            <xsl:if test= " ./generic:SeriesKey/generic:Value/@value = 'ABZINS7'">
            
                <Data>
                    <Year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(./generic:Obs/generic:ObsDimension/@value,'-')"/>
                    </Year>
                    <Month>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(./generic:Obs/generic:ObsDimension/@value,'-')"/>
                    </Month>
                    <RatePercentList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./generic:Obs" >
                        <RatePercent>
                           <xsl:value-of select="./generic:ObsValue/@value"/>
                        </RatePercent>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </RatePercentList>
                </Data>
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
                
            </ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent>
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected output**

I am expecting an output based upon below format

```
<ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent xmlns:xslt-version="MonthlyDiscounts_XSLT_26/06/2022"
                                                                xmlns:ns1="urn:ates:SI">
   <Data>
      <Year>2015</Year>
      <Month>01</Month>
      <RatePercentList>
         <RatePercent>3.07</RatePercent>
         <RatePercent>1.07</RatePercent>
      </RatePercentList>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Month>01</Month>
      <RatePercentList>
         <RatePercent>3.05</RatePercent>
         <RatePercent>1.05</RatePercent>
        
      </RatePercentList>
   </Data>
</ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent>
```

Thank you very much for your help

Best Regards,
Sateesh

Comment: Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both. If you are not sure which version your processor supports, find out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: Thank you for your help @michael.hor257k.  need XSLT 2.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **XSLT 2.0** you can produce the result you show by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.sdmx.org/resources/sdmxml/schemas/v2_1/data/generic">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent xmlns:xslt-version="MonthlyDiscounts_XSLT_26/06/2022" xmlns:ns1="urn:siemens.com:Rates:SIE_I_T_S4_FIN1.0">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//Obs" group-by="ObsDimension/@value">
            <Data>
                <Year>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current-grouping-key(), '-')"/>
                </Year>
                <Month>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(current-grouping-key(), '-')"/>
                </Month>
                <RatePercentList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <RatePercent>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ObsValue/@value"/>
                        </RatePercent>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </RatePercentList>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </ns1:DiscountInterestRatePercent>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To include only data from `Series` whose `SeriesKey` value is `"ABZINS7"`, change:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//Obs" group-by="ObsDimension/@value">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//Series[SeriesKey/Value/@value='ABZINS7']/Obs" group-by="ObsDimension/@value">
```

Untested, because your example does not allow testing of this condition.

Comment: Hello Michael,

Your XSLT provides an my expected format of output, However there should be also filter required  in the SeriesKey value while grouping these values. because we have multiple SeriesKeys where it requires only respective one.

<generic:SeriesKey>  
                <generic:Value id="BBK_SEDI_CALCULATION" value="ABZINS7"></generic:Value>        
            </generic:SeriesKey>

Example of filter
<xsl:if test= " ./generic:SeriesKey/generic:Value/@value = 'ABZINS7'">

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If you have additional requirements, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: Hi Michael,

If condition is also part my actual code, could you please take  a look once again in my XSLT

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Hi Michael, Would it be possible to provide code in XSLT 1.0  version? it seems for-each-group is not supported by my application

Comment: If you cannot use XSLT 2.0 then don't tag your question as `xslt-2.0` - and don't say that you need XSLT 2.0 when explicitly asked.

Comment: Understood Michael, my understanding was my application supports both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0. by implementing XSLT 2.0 code is bit lower and easy as compare to XSLT 1.0, for that reason i requested

Comment: Hi Michael, Created a post in XSLT 1.0